# Prove that $T$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{4} $ over real vector space $H$ of self-adjoint complex matrices of $2\times 2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R} ^ {4} \to \mathbb{C} ^ {2\times 2} $ the function defined by

$$T (x, y, z, w) = \begin {bmatrix}{w + x}&{y + iz}\\{y-iz}&{w-x} \end {bmatrix}$$

Prove that $T$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{4} $ over real vector space $H$ of self-adjoint complex matrices of $2\times2$.

Can somebody help me? I don't understand

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: What do you mean by an isomorphism here? If you ask it to be an isomorphism of linear spaces, observe that $T(\lambda v)$ is not the same as $\lambda T(v)$, because of the product $wx$.

Comment: He almost certainly means $w - x$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong   Yes sorry is w-x thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, but one way is to use the following hint: a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a vector space isomorphism if and only if $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$ and $\ker(T) = \{0\}$.

(This actually holds only for finite dimensional spaces)